# How to use metric_relabel_configs on some metrics simultaneously?

Tags: prometheus, metrics, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

I have more 3 metrics

jmx_config_reload_.21830123u_created{namespace="1"}

jmx_config_reload_.182308912_created{namespace="2"}

jmx_config_reload_.2312312cd_created{namespace="3"}

...

I am want in a metric load all metrics.

```
- job_name: 'jmx-exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.0.87:109877']
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: jmx_config_reload_.*_created
      target_label: __name__
      replacement: jmx_test_metric_relabel_all
      action: replace
```

My rule

```
    groups:
      - name: test of relabeling 
        rules:
        - alert: test of relabeling 
          expr: jmx_test_metric_relabel_all != 0
          for: 1m
          labels:
            severity: ATENCAO
          annotations:
            summary: test of relabeling
```

This procedure not work, because load only first metric.

Please, can someone help me with this?